# Graphql pulling data for pagination

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-tools

I have the following schema

```
User {
    username: String!
    name: String!
    posts(page: Int!): [Post]
}

Post {
    title: String!
    description: String
}
```

And in query

```
type Query {
    user(username: String!): User
}
```

In the resolvers I have defined `Query -> user` and also `user -> posts`
And when I pull the data I use:

```
{
    user(username: 'pewpewlasers'){
        username
        name
        posts(page: 1){
            title
            description
        }
    }
}
```

It's working great. Now my question is how do I efficiently pull the second page in an infinite scroll situation (with load more button at the end). I could use:

```
{
    user(username: 'pewpewlasers'){
        username
        name
        posts(page: 2){
            title
            description
        }
    }
}
```

But pulling the user again seems unnecessary, I just need posts for a load more. Is there a built in way graphql handles this? Or do I have to define a separate `posts(page: Int!, username: String!)` query

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can approach this:

1. Create an intermediate type, like `UserRelations` specifically
   for the purpose of providing an entry point for these types of
   queries without having to go via the User. This is the simplest way,
   and i've done it before, but it feels nasty to mess with data
   modelling in this way.
2. Make it so that whenever you resolve a `User`, you inspect what fields are 
   being requested. If you're only asking for fields that don't require 
   loading the User (i.e. relations-only), return a dummy object instead of making the data fetch. 
   This is more involved, because it means looking at the fields AST in your 
   resolvers, but getting comfortable with this is the key to most performance optimisations with GraphQL.